# Using a function to reduce re-writing code but changing the output semi-significantly

Tags: php

Well, I have a function that draws links that act like tabs on a web page. Basically, I have an array of links to use as tabs, all of this nature:

```
$aTabs[] = array("Mode" => "something", "Title" => "Something Else");
```

Once I have added all the tabs, I would like to use this function to print them:

```
function drawTabs($aTabs, $sFilename) {
global $iMode;

foreach ($aTabs as $aTab) {
    $sClass = "Tab";
    if ($iMode == $aTab["Mode"]) {
        $sClass .= " CurTab";
    }
    echo "<a class=\"{$sClass}\" href=\"{$sFilename}?Mode={$aTab["Mode"]}\">{$aTab["Title"]}</a>\n";
}
```

}

So that seems all fine and dandy as it is. It works just fine.

I would also like to use it in another part of the site, which is using URL rewriting to make things look a little neater. In that part of the site, the output needs to be

```
echo "<a class=\"{$sClass}\" href=\"{$sFilename}/{$aTab["Mode"]}/\">{$aTab["Title"]}</a>\n";
```

I was thinking of adding in a string replace that would do something like this:

```
str_replace("[mode]", $aTab["Mode"], $sFilename);
```

so that I could call

```
drawTabs($aTabs, "/some/place/on/my/site/[mode]/");
```

and most likely adding in a conditional so that if there is no '[mode]' in $sFilename, it would just add it to the end using '?Mode=$aTab["Mode"]'.

My question is, does my logic seem correct, or is there some more simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be something like this

```
function drawTabs($aTabs, $sFilename, $sFormat = null) {
    global $iMode;

    $sFormat = $sFormat ?: "<a class=\"[class]\" href=\"[fileName]?Mode=[mode]\">[title]</a>\n";

    foreach ($aTabs as $aTab) {
        $sClass = "Tab";
        if ($iMode == $aTab["Mode"]) {
            $sClass .= " CurTab";
        }

        $replacements = array(
            '[class]' => $sClass,
            '[fileName]' => $sFilename,
            '[mode]' => $aTab["Mode"],
            '[title]' => $aTab['Title'],
            );
            echo strtr($sFormat, $replacements);

    }
}
```

Then to use it

```
$sFormat = "<a class=\"[class]\" href=\"[fileName]/[mode]/\">[title]</a>\n";

drawTabs($aTabs, $sFilename, $sFormat);
```

Comment: Nice answer. You could rewrite it using replacement tokens like OP said and one of string functions like `strtr` or `str_replace`.

Comment: Thanks! That's basically what I ended up doing. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something simple. And you blew my mind with the simplified ternary operator! Learn something new every day!

Comment: Yup, that is new in php 5.3. I suggest reading release notes of every new major version, you learn a bunch of new stuff. I can't wait until my workplace updates to 5.4 and I can use the shortened array syntax.